# Win32(EvtSubscribe) callback works in .exe but not in dll

Tags: winapi, dll

I have a small code which parse a event viewer of the system to find required data. Now this code works fine when .exe is created but not in .dll.
How do i listen to an event which i have subscribed for inside a dll.

Are there any better way to implement EvtSubscribe() and SubscriptionCallback() in .dll ?

**[Full Source Code on Github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Mandar-Shinde/EventCop/master/EventCop.cpp)**

Is this behaviour because i have skipped DllMain() function?

**main()**

```
DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
EVT_HANDLE hSubscription = NULL;

hSubscription = EvtSubscribe(NULL, NULL, pwsPath, pwsQuery, NULL, NULL,
    (EVT_SUBSCRIBE_CALLBACK)SubscriptionCallback, EvtSubscribeStartAtOldestRecord);
if (NULL == hSubscription)
{       
    //some code
    return;
}
```

**Callback**
 gets called when .exe is build but not in .dll

```
// The callback that receives the events that match the query criteria. 
DWORD WINAPI SubscriptionCallback(EVT_SUBSCRIBE_NOTIFY_ACTION action, PVOID pContext, EVT_HANDLE hEvent)
{
    DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    switch (action)
    {
        //some code

    case EvtSubscribeActionDeliver:
        if (ERROR_SUCCESS != (status = PrintEvent(hEvent)))
        {
            goto cleanup;
        }
        break;
    }

cleanup:
        return status; // The service ignores the returned status.
}

 DWORD PrintEvent(EVT_HANDLE hEvent)
{
 // print
}
```

Comment: A DLL without a `DllMain` cannot be loaded for execution. Enable the [show loader snaps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556886.aspx) option using [GFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549557.aspx) to diagnose these sorts of problems.

Comment: @IInspectable The MSDN states that DlMain is "An optional entry point into a dynamic-link library (DLL)." It's not necessary for the programmer to supply a DllMain since the C run-time provides one. In fact, a DllMain supplied by the programmer will be called by the C run-time supplied entry point.

Comment: @MarcSherman: `DllMain` is not optional, as far as the system is concerned. It is optional, if you use a library that provides a default implementation, in case you aren't providing one.

Comment: @IInspectable As far as the system is concerned, we're talking about IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.AddressOfEntryPoint which the MSDN says "The entry point function is optional for DLLs. When no entry point is present, this member is zero." See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Your `main` function is not called when the DLL is loaded. You may want to export a new function (with same code), and call that function from the EXE. Alternatively, you could use `DllMain`, start a new thread from there, and then call `EvtSubscribe` from the thread. It is highly recommended to NOT call such functions directly from `DllMain`.

Comment: @IInspectable,@MarcSherman If we don't use DLLMain() in code and register dll from command prompt (regsvr32.exe mydll.dll) will this provide same functionality dllmain() or it is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to double check the call EvtClose. If you call this, the subscription callback will not be called.

There is nothing to do with DllMain.